# How do I dump an entire impala database

Tags: impala

Is there a way to dump all the schema / data of an impala database so I can recreate in a new database instance?

Something akin to what mysqldump does?

Answer (score 1):

Yes ,

1. you can take all data from impala warehouse ( usually /user/hive/warehouse)
   use dictcp to copy from one cluster to other cluster in same location
2. Fire show create table  to get schema of each table and just change location to destination location

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no DUMP command (or something similar):
http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-impala/latest/topics/impala_shell_commands.html

I think the best solution will be to use only external tables in one database.
That way, you can know where your data is saved, and potentially copy it in another place.

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table_name(one_field INT, another_field BIGINT,
     another_field1 STRING)
 COMMENT 'This is an external table'
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\054'
 STORED AS TEXTFILE
 LOCATION '<my_hdfs_location>';
```